# How to convert from a dtype('o') to a dtype(float) in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a way to read this csv into python 2.7 and turn it into a (3,22000) array.  For some reason I haven't been able to do it, no matter which way i try, I either get a groupn of strings in an array that i cant convert or an array seen below that won't convert to floats or allow computations to be done on them.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

For the record it says the shape is (22000,), which I'm unsure about also.

```
In [126]: import csv
import numpy as np

with open("Data.csv") as sd:
ri = []
dv = []
for row in csv.reader(sd):
    if row != ["ccx","ccy","ccz","cellVolumes","Cell Type"]:
        nrow = []
        for val in row[0:3]:
            val = float(val)
            nrow.append(val)
        ri.append(nrow)

        nrow = []
        for val in row[3:4]:
            val = float(val)
            nrow.append(val)
        dv.append(nrow)

ri = np.array(ri)
ri
```

.

```
Out[126]: array([[-0.179967, -0.38936, -0.46127], [-0.0633236, -0.407683, -0.542979],
   [-0.125841, -0.494202, -0.412042], ...,
   [-0.0116821, 0.764493, 0.573541], [0.630377, 0.469657, 0.442017],
   [0.248253, 0.615365, 0.354134]], dtype=object
```

Comment: Check the length of those sublists.  If they are all the same I'd expect a 2d array; but if they differ (most 3, but some 0, 2,4 etc) then the best it can do is give you a 1d array of 'objects' - the lists.

Comment: Its a 3x22000 file. Is there an easy way to run through that and see if each sublist has the same length?

Comment: Wait, isn't it (22000,) shape?  I would just do `[len(x) for in x in ri]` before passing it to `np.array`.  Maybe apply a `max` and `min`.  A list comprehension like that won't take long.

Comment: Yes that's what python says.  I'm saying the excel file itself is 3x22000.  I tried `[len(x) for in x in ri]` but it claims that `in` is an invalid syntax.

Comment: Never mind I got it the comprehension to work.  Turns out there's literally one line of zero right in the middle.  So any idea how to fix this?  I would really appreciate the help, this has been killing me.  Maybe there's some sort of if statement i can include that doesn't allow any rows that don't have 3 values in them to pass? Any idea how to code that, because I'm not sure

Comment: Just figured it out.  You're the best man, I can't believe there was one list of zero in it.  Thank you so much for pointing that out. Let me know if there's some way I can award you or upvote your comment or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(from the helpful comments)

Check the length of those sublists. If they are all the same I'd expect a 2d array; but if they differ (most 3, but some 0, 2,4 etc) then the best it can do is give you a 1d array of 'objects' - the lists.

I would just do `[len(x) for x in ri]` before passing it to `np.array`. Maybe apply a `max` and `min`. A list comprehension like that won't take long.

Comment: Can't upvote, not enough rep yet, but I'll come back once I do!

Comment: Also, its [len(x) for x in ri].